# How to open an Accordion from a external link

Tags: javascript, scroll, anchor, accordion

I'm trying to scroll to an ID on a different page that is inside a closed accordion. I have tried a few different ways, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm guessing there is maybe something I could implement in my current Javascript code that could achieve this? Thanks

Anchor Tag -

```
<a href="/pagename#test">This is a Test</a>
```

Accordion -

```
<details>    
  <summary>
    <div class="box box">
      <div class="box-study box-study--content">
        Accordion Name
      </div>
      <div class="box-study box-study--image">
    <div class="studyicon">
            <img src="/iconimage.png">
    </div>
   
      </div>
    </div>

    </summary>


<div class="inside themeGrey">


   <h3 id="#test">Name of area I want to scroll too</h3>

</div>

     </details>
```

Javascript for the Accordion

```
/** Class representing an accordion component. */
class Accordion {
  /**
   * Create an accordion component
   *
   * Accepts a container element which should contain a list of `details` and
   * `summary` elements
   *
   * @param   {String}  selector  The container element.
   */
  constructor(selector) {
    if (typeof selector !== "string") {
      console.error("Accordion selector must be a string");
      return;
    }

    this._container = document.querySelector(selector);
    
    this._container.addEventListener('click', (event) => this._toggle(event));
  }

  /**
   * Static method to close all `details` elements that are descendants of the
   * passed in container element.
   *
   * @param   {(HTMLElement|HTMLDocument)}  [elem=document]  The container
   */
  static closeAll(elem = document) {
    const opened = elem.querySelectorAll("details[open]");
    for (const elem of opened) {
      elem.removeAttribute("open");
    }
  }

  /** Private methods */
  
  /**
   * Toggle the accordion elements
   *
   * @param   {Event}  event  The triggering event object
   */
  _toggle(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const details = event.target.closest("details");
    
    if (details.hasAttribute("open")) {
      details.removeAttribute("open");
    } else {
      Accordion.closeAll(this._container);
      details.toggleAttribute("open");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On page load you could check if the URL has a hash. Then see if the element exists. If it exists check if it's inside a details field, if so open the accordion and scroll to the element.

See `_loadFromHash` for implementation details.

```js
/** Class representing an accordion component. */
class Accordion {
  /**
   * Create an accordion component
   *
   * Accepts a container element which should contain a list of `details` and
   * `summary` elements
   *
   * @param   {String}  selector  The container element.
   */
  constructor(selector) {
    if (typeof selector !== "string") {
      console.error("Accordion selector must be a string");
      return;
    }

    this._container = document.querySelector(selector);
    
    this._container.addEventListener('click', this._toggle, false);
    
    this._loadFromHash();
  }

  /**
   * Static method to close all `details` elements that are descendants of the
   * passed in container element.
   *
   * @param   {(HTMLElement|HTMLDocument)}  [elem=document]  The container
   */
  static closeAll(elem = document) {
    const opened = elem.querySelectorAll("details[open]");
    for (const elem of opened) {
      elem.removeAttribute("open");
    }
  }

  /** Private methods */
  
  /**
   * Toggle the accordion elements
   *
   * @param   {Event}  event  The triggering event object
   */
  _toggle(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const details = event.target.closest("details");
    
    if (details.hasAttribute("open")) {
      details.removeAttribute("open");
    } else {
      Accordion.closeAll(this._container);
      details.toggleAttribute("open");
    }
  }
  
  _loadFromHash() {
    // FOR DEMO SINCE THERE IS NO HASH IN STACK OVERFLOW SNIPPET, REMOVE LINE IN REAL APP
    window.location.hash = '#test';
    
    // Exit if no hash in url
    if(!window.location.hash) return;
    
    // Get element from hash, exit if not found
    const element = document.querySelector('#test');
    if(!element) return;
    
    // Get parent details from element, exit if not found
    const details = element.closest('details');
    if(!details) return;
    
    // Open accordion and scoll it into view
    details.toggleAttribute("open");
    element.scrollIntoView();
  }
}

new Accordion('details');
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <div class="box box">
      <div class="box-study box-study--content">
        Accordion Name
      </div>
      <div class="box-study box-study--image">
        <div class="studyicon">
          <img src="/iconimage.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </summary>

  <div class="inside themeGrey">
     <h3 id="test">Name of area I want to scroll too</h3>
  </div>
</details>
```

Comment: I tried this out but couldn't get it working... thank you though

Comment: Could you send a working JsFiddle?